# In Excel, How can I calculate number of weekends between 2 dates with alternate saturday

Tags: excel-formula

In Excel, How can I calculate number of weekends between 2 dates when every Sunday & alternate Saturday are considered weekend. One thing I am sure that alternate Saturday will come on even weeks i.e. on Week 2,4,6 and so on.

For examples: From Date is 11/5/2015 & To Date is 11/30/2015. That means Weekends would be 11/8/2015,11/14/2015,11/15/2015,11/21/2015,11/28/2015 & 11/29/2015. Means 5 total weekends according to alternate Saturdays

Comment: Some illustrated examples please!

Comment: @ZoffDino for e.g. From Date is 11/5/2015 & To Date is 11/30/2015. that means Weekends would be 11/8/2015,11/14/2015,11/15/2015,11/21/2015,11/28/2015 & 11/29/2015. Means 6 total weekends according to alternate Saturdays.

Comment: Have you tried the answer provided?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is complex because of the different treatment applied to alternate Saturdays. For this reason, I proposed to create an `Excel Table` to hold the data with the weekend days for the period required.

This solution assumes the following:

1. Weeks of the year are counted using the System 1 method of the [WEEKNUM function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/WEEKNUM-function-E5C43A03-B4AB-426C-B411-B18C13C75340)
2. Weeks begin on Mondays
3. Data with dates to process is located in Sheet1 at `B6:D10` *(adjust ranges in formulas as required)*

*Implementation steps:*

1. In a new worksheet named “tWeekendDays” create an `Excel Table` *(name it* `tWkendDays`*)* to hold the weekend days for the required period *(i.e. from 01-Nov-2015 to 22-Jan-2017; adjust as needed)*. This table calculates only the required days as per the following conditions:

   Weekend days includes:

   a. All Sundays

   b. All Saturdays for even weeks numbers *(in line with assumptions 1 and 2)*

   The section above the `Excel Table` has a field to enter in `B3` the starting date to automatically calculate the table *(01-Nov-2015 for this demo, see Fig. 1)*

   The `Excel Table` is located at `B6:D104` and contains these fields:

   **Date**: Enter this formula in `B7` and copy till last record

   ```
   =IF(EXACT(B6,B$6),$B$3,
   SUM($B6,
   CHOOSE(WEEKDAY($B6,2),5,4,3,2,1,1,
   IF(ISEVEN($C6),7,6))))
   ```

   **Week.Nbr**: Enter this formula in `C7` and copy till last record

   ```
   =WEEKNUM($B7,2)
   ```

   **Weekend.Days** : Enter this formula in `D7` and copy till last record

   ```
   =IF(WEEKDAY($B7,2)=7,1,
   IF(AND(WEEKDAY($B7,2)=6,ISEVEN($C7)),1,0))
   ```

[image]

*Fig. 1*

2. Then in `Sheet1` enter this formula in `D7` and copy till last record

   ```
   =SUMIFS(tWkendDays[Weekend.Days],
   tWkendDays[Date],">="&$B7,tWkendDays[Date],"<="&$C7)
   ```

[image]

*Fig. 2*